# Eclipse building - exclude from jar packaging but include into final product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, packaging

I am using a Derby local (embedded) database for one of my RCP projects. The database is located within the project folder structure in eclipse and is checked to be included in the build.

My folder structure in Eclipse is:

```
projectname 
I
I-  src
I
I-  database
I      I
I      I-project database here
I
I
I-  icons
...
```

The Eclipse build process now includes the database folder including the subfolders into the jar file of the project.

Unfortunately I can not convice Derby to look inside the packaged jar file and use the database there, so I would like to have the database, which I am using and filling while developing the software, excluded from the jar packaging, but included into the later build product.

My dream would be to have the product folder structure like this:

```
productname
I
I- configuration
I
I- database ...!
I
I- jre
I 
I- p2
I
I- plugins
I
I- artifacts.xml
I- productname.exe
I- productname.ini
```

Can this somehow be achieved with the PDE build process?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer, but I can offer some suggestions.

Firstly, you could create a new plug-in to contain just your database. You could then export this plug-in as an exploded (folder-based) plug-in, rather than as a jar. This would allow Derby to access the database files and you could selectively include the plug-in when you're building your product.

Another option that might be worth investigating is the non-plug-in data facility of features. It seems that features offer a mechanism where you can manage non-plug-in data separately to plug-ins, and that this supports update sites. I've not used the facility myself, but there's a thread that might be of interest here: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/platform-update-dev/msg00807.html